# Spring Batch JPA SaveALL() and SAVE() not working and no Error

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-batch, querydsl, module-pattern

I wrote the code, but the jpa is not saved. select statement works but save or saveall doesn't. No way to solve it?

Existing batches except for commercial work well, but only the newly created commercial step does not work.

Below is the corresponding code.

BatchConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer{

  private final Integer CHUNK_SIZE = 1;

  private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
  private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

  // Call Step
  private final CallLogReader callLogReader;
  private final CallLogStatisticsWriter callLogStatisticsWriter;

  // Click Step
  private final ClickLogReader clickLogReader;
  private final ClickLogStatisticsWriter clickLogStatisticsWriter;

  // Exposure Step
  private final ExposureLogReader exposureLogReader;
  private final ExposureAdvertisementLogStatisticsWriter exposureAdvertisementLogStatisticsWriter;
  private final ExposureChannelLogStatisticsWriter exposureChannelLogStatisticsWriter;
  private final ExposureVendorLogStatisticsWriter exposureVendorLogStatisticsWriter;
  private final ExposureLogStatisticsWrtier exposureLogStatisticsWrtier;

  // Search Step
  private final SearchLogReader searchLogReader;
  private final SearchAdministrationLogStatisticsWriter searchAdministrationLogStatisticsWriter;
  private final SearchProspectLogStatisticsWriter searchProspectLogStatisticsWriter;

  // AdvertieseCommercial Step
  private final CommercialReader commercialReader;
  private final AdpoiWriter adpoiWriter;

  // @Autowired(required = true)
  // private JpaTransactionManager transactionManager;

  @Bean(name = "callJob")
  public Job callJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("call")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(callStep())
        .end()
        .build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "clickJob")
  public Job clickJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("click")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(clickStep())
        .end()
        .build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "exposureJob")
  public Job exposureJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("exposure")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(exposureStep())
        .end()
        .build();
  }

  // 가망 통계
  @Bean(name = "searchJob")
  public Job searchJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("search")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(searchStep())
        .end()
        .build();
  }

  //네스 data 저장
  @Bean(name = "commercialJob")
  public Job commercialJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("commercial")
      .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
      .flow(commercialStep())
      .end()
      .build();
  }


  @Bean
  public Step callStep() {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get(StepState.CALL.toString())
        .<List<CallStatistics>, List<CallStatistics>> chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
        .reader(callLogReader)
        .writer(callLogStatisticsWriter)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step clickStep() {
    
    return stepBuilderFactory.get(StepState.CLICK.toString())
        .<List<ClickStatistics>,List<ClickStatistics>> chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
        .reader(clickLogReader)
        .writer(clickLogStatisticsWriter)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step exposureStep() {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get(StepState.EXPOSURE.toString())
        .<ExposureDto, ExposureDto >chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
        .reader(exposureLogReader)
        .writer(compositeExposureLogStatisticsWriters())
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step searchStep() {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get(StepState.SEARCH.toString())
        .<SearchDto, SearchDto >chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
        .reader(searchLogReader)
        .writer(compositeSearchLogStatisticsWriters())
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step commercialStep() {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get(StepState.COMMERCIAL.toString())
      .<List<AdPoiDto>, List<AdPoiDto>>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
      .reader(commercialReader)
      .writer(adpoiWriter)
      // .transactionManager(transactionManager)
      .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public CompositeItemWriter<ExposureDto> compositeExposureLogStatisticsWriters() {
    CompositeItemWriter<ExposureDto> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
    compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(exposureAdvertisementLogStatisticsWriter,
        exposureChannelLogStatisticsWriter, exposureLogStatisticsWrtier, exposureVendorLogStatisticsWriter));

    return compositeItemWriter;
  }

  @Bean
  public CompositeItemWriter<SearchDto> compositeSearchLogStatisticsWriters() {
    CompositeItemWriter<SearchDto> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
    compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(searchAdministrationLogStatisticsWriter,
        searchProspectLogStatisticsWriter));

    return compositeItemWriter;
  }
}
```

writer

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@StepScope
@Component
public class AdpoiWriter implements ItemWriter<List<AdPoiDto>>{

  @Autowired
  private final AdvertisementCommercialRepository advertisementCommercialRepository;

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends List<AdPoiDto>> adPoiDtos) {
    List<AdPoi> adPoiList = new ArrayList<>();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    for (List<AdPoiDto> dtoList : adPoiDtos) {

      for (AdPoiDto dto : dtoList) {
        AdPoi adPoi = objectMapper.convertValue(dto, AdPoi.class);
        adPoiList.add(adPoi);
      }

    }

    // AdPoi adPoi = new AdPoi();
    // System.out.println("@@@@ : Adpoi :  " + adPoiList.get(0));
    // advertisementCommercialRepository.save(adPoi);
    // advertisementCommercialRepository.insertData(adPoiList.get(0).getOp_cl(), adPoiList.get(0).getTelno_cl());
    advertisementCommercialRepository.saveAll(adPoiList);
    // Iterable<AdPoi> adPois = advertisementCommercialRepository.findAll();
    // for (AdPoi adPoi : adPois) {
    //   System.out.println("@@@ 11234" + adPoi.toString());
    // }
    log.info("@@@ Insert ad_poi End");
    
  }
    
}
```

Terminal log that appears when the batch is executed

```
2023-06-22 10:22:58.213  INFO 23995 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-06-22 10:22:58.214  INFO 23995 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-06-22 10:22:58.274  INFO 23995 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 60 ms
@@@@ 2023-06-21
2023-06-22 10:22:58.579 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:58.581 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
2023-06-22 10:22:58.673 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:58.674 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
2023-06-22 10:22:58.693 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:58.693 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
2023-06-22 10:22:58.769 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:22:58.775 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]
2023-06-22 10:22:58.841 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:22:58.842 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
2023-06-22 10:22:58.865 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:22:58.872 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, KEY_NAME, TYPE_CD, STRING_VAL, DATE_VAL, LONG_VAL, DOUBLE_VAL, IDENTIFYING) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
2023-06-22 10:22:58.910 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:22:58.911 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT (SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT, JOB_EXECUTION_ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)]
2023-06-22 10:22:58.959  INFO 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=commercial]] launched with the following parameters: [{TIME=1687310578370}]
2023-06-22 10:22:58.998 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:58.998 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.019 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:59.019 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.037 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:22:59.039 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?,  STATUS = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, CREATE_TIME = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.093 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:59.093 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, VERSION, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where JOB_INSTANCE_ID = ? order by JOB_EXECUTION_ID desc]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.103 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:59.103 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID, KEY_NAME, TYPE_CD, STRING_VAL, DATE_VAL, LONG_VAL, DOUBLE_VAL, IDENTIFYING from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.136 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:59.136 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT STEP_EXECUTION_ID, STEP_NAME, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, COMMIT_COUNT, READ_COUNT, FILTER_COUNT, WRITE_COUNT, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, READ_SKIP_COUNT, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, ROLLBACK_COUNT, LAST_UPDATED, VERSION from BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? order by STEP_EXECUTION_ID]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.186 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:59.186 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT  SE.STEP_EXECUTION_ID, SE.STEP_NAME, SE.START_TIME, SE.END_TIME, SE.STATUS, SE.COMMIT_COUNT, SE.READ_COUNT, SE.FILTER_COUNT, SE.WRITE_COUNT, SE.EXIT_CODE, SE.EXIT_MESSAGE, SE.READ_SKIP_COUNT, SE.WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, SE.PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, SE.ROLLBACK_COUNT, SE.LAST_UPDATED, SE.VERSION, JE.JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JE.START_TIME, JE.END_TIME, JE.STATUS, JE.EXIT_CODE, JE.EXIT_MESSAGE, JE.CREATE_TIME, JE.LAST_UPDATED, JE.VERSION from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION JE, BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION SE where       SE.JOB_EXECUTION_ID in (SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where JOB_INSTANCE_ID = ?)      and SE.JOB_EXECUTION_ID = JE.JOB_EXECUTION_ID       and SE.STEP_NAME = ? order by SE.START_TIME desc, SE.STEP_EXECUTION_ID desc]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.236 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:59.236 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, VERSION, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where JOB_INSTANCE_ID = ? order by JOB_EXECUTION_ID desc]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.245 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:59.245 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID, KEY_NAME, TYPE_CD, STRING_VAL, DATE_VAL, LONG_VAL, DOUBLE_VAL, IDENTIFYING from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.273 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:59.273 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT STEP_EXECUTION_ID, STEP_NAME, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, COMMIT_COUNT, READ_COUNT, FILTER_COUNT, WRITE_COUNT, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, READ_SKIP_COUNT, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, ROLLBACK_COUNT, LAST_UPDATED, VERSION from BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? order by STEP_EXECUTION_ID]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.371 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:22:59.371 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT into BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION(STEP_EXECUTION_ID, VERSION, STEP_NAME, JOB_EXECUTION_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, COMMIT_COUNT, READ_COUNT, FILTER_COUNT, WRITE_COUNT, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, READ_SKIP_COUNT, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, ROLLBACK_COUNT, LAST_UPDATED) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.394 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:22:59.395 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT (SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT, STEP_EXECUTION_ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.431  INFO 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [COMMERCIAL]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.439 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:22:59.439 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?, STATUS = ?, COMMIT_COUNT = ?, READ_COUNT = ?, FILTER_COUNT = ?, WRITE_COUNT = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, READ_SKIP_COUNT = ?, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT = ?, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT = ?, ROLLBACK_COUNT = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.456 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:22:59.456 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.554 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:22:59.554 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2023-06-22 10:22:59.626  INFO 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] c.z.w.m.b.s.c.CommercialReader           : Commercial Batch START
2023-06-22 10:22:59.626  INFO 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] c.z.w.m.b.s.c.CommercialReader           : Commercial STEP DATE : 2023-06-21
2023-06-22 10:23:00.408  INFO 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] c.z.w.m.b.s.c.c.AdpoiWriter              : @@@ Insert ad_poi End
2023-06-22 10:23:00.413 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:23:00.413 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.436 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:23:00.436 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?, STATUS = ?, COMMIT_COUNT = ?, READ_COUNT = ?, FILTER_COUNT = ?, WRITE_COUNT = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, READ_SKIP_COUNT = ?, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT = ?, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT = ?, ROLLBACK_COUNT = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.454 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:23:00.454 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.502  INFO 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] c.z.w.m.b.s.c.CommercialReader           : Commercial Batch START
2023-06-22 10:23:00.502  INFO 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] c.z.w.m.b.s.c.CommercialReader           : Commercial STEP DATE : 2023-06-21
2023-06-22 10:23:00.502 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:23:00.502 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.520 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:23:00.521 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?, STATUS = ?, COMMIT_COUNT = ?, READ_COUNT = ?, FILTER_COUNT = ?, WRITE_COUNT = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, READ_SKIP_COUNT = ?, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT = ?, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT = ?, ROLLBACK_COUNT = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.537 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:23:00.538 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.587 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:23:00.587 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.619  INFO 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [COMMERCIAL] executed in 1s188ms
2023-06-22 10:23:00.627 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:23:00.627 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?, STATUS = ?, COMMIT_COUNT = ?, READ_COUNT = ?, FILTER_COUNT = ?, WRITE_COUNT = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, READ_SKIP_COUNT = ?, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT = ?, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT = ?, ROLLBACK_COUNT = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.645 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:23:00.645 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.692 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:23:00.692 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.740 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:23:00.741 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.760 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2023-06-22 10:23:00.760 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.777 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2023-06-22 10:23:00.777 DEBUG 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?,  STATUS = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, CREATE_TIME = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
2023-06-22 10:23:00.817  INFO 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=commercial]] completed with the following parameters: [{TIME=1687310578370}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 1s743ms
2023-06-22 10:23:00.818  INFO 23995 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] c.z.w.m.b.q.QuartzJobLauncher            : Status : COMPLETED
```

DB uses only one instance,
There are no newly overridden methods in the Repository.

It's not a project I made, it's a module pattern project, and this project uses querydsl. Maybe it has something to do with why querydsl doesn't work?

I tried using JPATransactionManager as well, but it failed.

Hope jpa save() or saveall() will work

Comment: I created adpoi's q class using QueryDsl, but to no avail.

Comment: After creating a separate service and controller in the batch project, accessing the url and executing saveall(), I confirmed that it was saved normally.

Comment: You need to use a JpaTransactionManager, but you said `I tried using JPATransactionManager as well, but it failed.`. Can you share how your trial? Since your class extends `DefaultBatchConfigurer`, you need to override `getTransacctionManager`  and return a `JpaTransactionManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `JpaTransactionManager`, but you said `I tried using JPATransactionManager as well, but it failed.`

You did not share how you tried that, but since your class extends `DefaultBatchConfigurer`, the expectation is that you override the `getTransacctionManager` method and return a `JpaTransactionManager`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to your advice, I put in some overriding code and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mahmoud Ben Hassine's answer, I solved it by adding that code.

```
@Autowired
private final DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
  return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```